# Testing backup solutions in virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, backup

I have Linux Mint. I want to test backup solutions inside virtual machine (dd, rsync, clonezilla, etc). The 2 questions are:

1. is it safe to do this (especially dd)?
2. does it have sense? I think filesystem is the same inside or outside virtual maching, but may be there are some differencies?

Answer (score 3):

It does make sense if what you want to do is test the methods that you will be using. (For example see how these commands work and if they work as you expect them to).

It is perfectly safe to use `dd` in a virtual machine as long as you haven't mounted (or otherwise made accessible) resources from your normal system. The virtual machine cannot make a change in the host system unless you explicitly give it access.